# Netsuite RESTlet

Tags: netsuite, restlet, suitescript

Example of Netsuite RESTlet that Can Retrieve, Delete or Create

Can somebody explain me theoretically what exactly is this code doing

ref:  https://tstdrv2433299.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4634148062.html

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Restlet
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/error'],
        function(record, error) {
    function doValidation(args, argNames, methodName) {
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            if (!args[i] && args[i] !== 0)
                throw error.create({
                    name: 'MISSING_REQ_ARG',
                    message: 'Missing a required argument: [' + argNames[i] + '] for method: ' + methodName
                });
    }
    // Get a standard NetSuite record
    function _get(context) {
        doValidation([context.recordtype, context.id], ['recordtype', 'id'], 'GET');
        return JSON.stringify(record.load({
            type: context.recordtype,
            id: context.id
        }));
    }
    // Delete a standard NetSuite record
    function _delete(context) {
        doValidation([context.recordtype, context.id], ['recordtype', 'id'], 'DELETE');
        record.delete({
            type: context.recordtype,
            id: context.id
        });
        return String(context.id);
    }
    // Create a NetSuite record from request params
    function post(context) {
        doValidation([context.recordtype], ['recordtype'], 'POST');
        var rec = record.create({
            type: context.recordtype
        });
        for (var fldName in context)
            if (context.hasOwnProperty(fldName))
                if (fldName !== 'recordtype')
                    rec.setValue(fldName, context[fldName]);
        var recordId = rec.save();
        return String(recordId);
    }
    // Upsert a NetSuite record from request param
    function put(context) {
        doValidation([context.recordtype, context.id], ['recordtype', 'id'], 'PUT');
        var rec = record.load({
            type: context.recordtype,
            id: context.id
        });
        for (var fldName in context)
            if (context.hasOwnProperty(fldName))
                if (fldName !== 'recordtype' && fldName !== 'id')
                    rec.setValue(fldName, context[fldName]);
        rec.save();
        return JSON.stringify(rec);
    }
    return {
        get: _get,
        delete: _delete,
        post: post,
        put: put
    };
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The example code creates a generalized restlet that allows you to perform generic crud operations on any recordtype in netsuite.

- When this restlet is called with the http `get` verb, it will return the specified record (specified by recordtype, and id).
- When this restlet is called with the http `post` verb, the restlet will create the specified record (specified by recordtype, and id).
- When this restlet is called with the http `put` verb, the restlet will update the specified record (specified by recordtype, and id).
- When this restlet is called with the http `delete` verb, the restlet will delete the specified record (specified by recordtype, and id).

Answer (score 1):

The header comment declares to NetSuite what API version and what script type this is. In this case [Restlet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4387799403.html) with [API version 2.x](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/part_4563537633.html)

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Restlet
 */
```

The [define](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4600491925.html) keyword declared what modules to import into the script, and the [moduleObject](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4424424173.html) (the entry point script).

In this example ['N/record'](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4267255811.html) and ['N/error'](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4243798608.html) is imported as **record** and **error**.

```
define(['N/record', 'N/error'],
        function(record, error) {
```

At the end if the file, there is returned an object that maps the [HTTP verbs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) to function:

```
return {
    get: _get,
    delete: _delete,
    post: post,
    put: put
};
```

In this example all these functions do some operations on the record object. Like: [record.load()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4267258486.html), [record.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4267283372.html) and [record.create()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4267258059.html)

They all also call the convenience function doValidation(), that is used to validate the input. It uses the [error module](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4243798608.html) to throw an error.

Notice that they all accept a parameter (here called context). Context will contain query parameters and post body.